# Run TreSpEx analysis

Tags: loops, tree

I am trying to run TreSpex analysis on a series of trees, which are saved in newick format as `.fasta.txt` files in a folder.
I have a list of Taxa names saved in a `.txt` file

I enter:

```
perl TreSpEx.v1.pl -fun e -ipt *fasta.txt -tf Taxa_List.txt
```

But it won't run. I tried writing a loop for each file within the folder but am not very good with them and my line of

```
for i in treefile/; do perl TreSpEx.v1.1.pl -fun e -ipt *.fasta.txt -tf Taxa_List.txt; done
```

won't work because `-ipt` apparently needs a name that starts with a letter or number

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you are actually doing the same thing as in first (but posible several times).

I'm not familiar with TreSpEx or know Bash very well for that matter (which it seems you are using), but you might try something like below.

```
for i in treefile/*.fasta.txt ; do
    perl TreSpEx.v1.1.pl -fun e -ipt $i -tf Taxa_List.txt;
done
```

Basically, you need to use a variable from the for loop (`i`) to pass name of each file to the command.